# An f(n) and g(n) that aren't upper bounds of each other

Tags: algorithm, big-o

As the title says, can someone name an f(n) and a g(n) where they aren't upper bounds of each other. I had absolutely no idea and put two random constants:

f(n) = 8

g(n) = 3

Still no idea

Comment: Try using n: `f(n) = n*n`

Comment: @user2864740 Assuming that "upper bound" is meant in the asymptotic, big O sense, n*n is an upper bound of 3 (that is `g` is in `O(n*n)`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, they are both O(1). I'd say they're both "equivalent" and both upper/lower bounds of each other.

I'm pretty sure

```
f(n) = sin(n)
g(n) = cos(n)
```

will work. If you take the limit as n approaches infinity, `f(n)/g(n)` does not converge, and neither will `g(n)/f(n)` converge. Therefore, neither is an upper bound of the other.

Please post in a comment if you're not sure about why limits are being used here, and I can explain in greater depth.

Comment: Damn that's a good one... Do you have another non-trig example, we never really used trig in class so wouldn't have even thought to use that one... But yeah that would work.

Comment: I think Gribouillis has a solution that is non-trig. It looks like it works. Feel free to comment here or on his post if there's anything that's unclear, and give him an upvote if you found it useful.

Answer (score 3):

Take `f(n)` be any positive value depending on `n` and

```
g(n) = n*f(n) if n is even else f(n)/n
```

Then, there is no constant A such that for n large enough `g(n) <= A f(n)`, and
there is no constant B such that for n large enough `f(n) <= B g(n)`. Thus g is not O(f) and f is not O(g).